# Аналог SET NAMES в MSSQL?

Tags: база-данных, кодировка, sql-server, php, mysql

Есть ли аналог `SET NAMES` в MSSQL? , использовать `ini_set` не предлагать, мне нужно именно аналог этой возможности (как в `MySQL`), только средствами `MSSQL` (2005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналога нет, ибо принцип работы с кодировкой в MS SQL другой. кодировкой (в MS SQL она называется COLLATION) могут обладать объекты системы - сервер, база данных, колонка таблицы. Также хинт COLLATION может содержаться в самом запросе (например, если нужно сравнить данных двух колонок с разными COLLATION'ами).
Для простоты работы с данными разных языков лучше создавать колонки типа Unicode - типы данных nchar() и nvarchar().